# Applescript copy excel cells incrementally as a part of a workflow

Tags: excel, applescript, increment, automator

I am a newbie to all of this, so please bear with me.

I have a list of numbers in column "B" of an Excel spreadsheet that I want to use an Applescript to copy one-at-a-time, paste into another application and then return and copy the next value in the list.

I set up Automator to select a cell, then copy to the clipboard. I then inserted an AppleScript to paste the number into the other application and do some keystrokes to complete the entry. I have successfully gotten a workflow to process ONE cell, but now I want to repeat the process with the next number in the next Excel cell.

I really don't care if I use Automator or not, I just wasn't sure how to write the excel part of the script.

Thanks (Mac X, Excel 2010)

Comment: [3. "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Check the "Watch me do" and LOOP automator actions. You can save and replay keyboard events. So probably you need: 1) activate Excel, 2.) WatchMeDo cursor-key-down to next cell 3.) run your current workflow 4.) LOOP (start again)

Comment: I have been looking online all day today and most of last Friday for examples that may help me with my issue. But none have addressed all of the criteria I am looking for. So I decided to ask my question here. I have become familiar with variables, but I don't see any answers regarding referencing Excel references and incrementing the process to the next cell.

Comment: I would have thought it would be a pretty common task to copy values from one cell in Excel, paste somewhere and return to the next cell down, copy, paste somewhere, etc. I can find where you insert a whole list in your code, but I've got thousands of numbers to process, so that seems impractical. The "Watch me do" wouldn't be able to know that what I'm telling it, is to go down a row, would it?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than copying and pasting values one-by-one you may find it more efficient to read the Excel values into a 2D array (AppleScript list of lists) then use AppleScript to loop through the values from the target column. Here's an example of how that might be done.

```
property targetCol : 2 --column B
property startRow : 2 -- if row 1 has headers
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    tell active sheet
        set theData to used range's value --> list of lists 2D matrix
        set rowCount to count theData
        repeat with rowNum from startRow to rowCount
            set cellVal to item {targetCol} of item {rowNum} of theData
            -- do something with cellVal here --> write value to the other app, etc.
        end repeat
    end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 0):

In Applescript, this would just be mimicking keystrokes on your computer:

```
repeat 10 times
   activate application "Microsoft Excel"
   tell application "System Events" to tell process "Microsoft Excel"
      keystroke "c" using command down -- Command "c" (copies active cell to clipboard)
      key code 36 -- return button (to go down one cell)
   end tell
   activate application "Other App"
   tell application "System Events" to tell process "Other App" to keystroke "v" using command down -- Command "v" (pastes stored data from clipboard)
end repeat
```